# How to call particular method of service using request url

Tags: c#, wcf, url

I am completely new here to write a web service in .net. So I follow [WCF tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650869/Creating-a-Self-Hosted-WCF-Service)

to write my service and I am able to access it remotely. But I am using the URL generated by project on browser. 
 Now I want to write some more methods in this project and access various methods with various URL's. Service should return me some response at postman in order to consume it in Xamarin.Forms PCL project. So if I have some methods in my service project how to get URL for that particular method. It may be GET or POST with parameter or without parameter.
It may be very basic question but I stuck here only.

Comment: if you using http bindings only - than better use Web API insted of WCF. Also it`s really good idea to post your code inside the question

Comment: I used Class Library project to develop this service. This is not actually WCF. I want to implement all service on Xamarin.Forms application. Are you sure I need to use Web API?

Comment: WCF and Web API are server side technologies difference between them - is that WCF basically RPC style and WEB API is pure REST. 

Xamarin - is client and it could consume any REST service, no matter what was used as a server.
   In case you using only http / https protocols it`s clear to use Web API.

Comment: Will you please suggest me some links to follow.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api  for the start

Comment: No way to using existing project to implement services? If it is please suggest.

Comment: might take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/821439/Getting-started-with-ASP-Net-Web-API-using-CodeF
but it`s bad idea to use technology you not familiar with.